# How to split a really long matrix

Tags: equations, formatting, amsmath, matrices, split

I have a really long matrix and I would like to show it in a split form once it reaches the wide limit of the page. I tried using split but it didn't work. I'm new to latex so there's many commands I don't know. Thanks.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}


\begin{document}



%%%% use split
\noindent % to emulate a preceding text

\[
\begin{split}

 \begin{split}

{
 \left[ \begin {array}{cccccccccccc} k_{p}+k_{c}&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&-k_{p
}&0&0\\ \noalign{\medskip}0&k_{p}+k_{c}&k_{p}&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&-k_{p}&0
\\ \noalign{\medskip}0&k_{p}&k_{p}+k_{{\it cu}}&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&-k_{p}&0
\\ \noalign{\medskip}0&0&0&-k_{m}\, \left( \cos \left( \alpha \right) 
 \right) ^{2}+k_{m}+k_{r}&-k_{m}\,\cos \left( \alpha \right) \sin
 \left( \alpha \right) &-k_{m}\,\sin \left( \alpha \right) &0&0&0&k_{m
}\, \left( \cos \left( \alpha \right)  \right) ^{2}-k_{m}&k_{m}\,\cos
 \left( \alpha \right) \sin \left( \alpha \right) &k_{m}\,\sin \left( 
\alpha \right) \\ \noalign{\medskip}0&0&0&-k_{m}\,\cos \left( \alpha
 \right) \sin \left( \alpha \right) &k_{m}\, \left( \cos \left( \alpha
 \right)  \right) ^{2}+k_{r}&k_{m}\,\cos \left( \alpha \right) &0&0&0&
k_{m}\,\cos \left( \alpha \right) \sin \left( \alpha \right) &-k_{m}\,
 \left( \cos \left( \alpha \right)  \right) ^{2}&-k_{m}\,\cos \left( 
\alpha \right) \\ \noalign{\medskip}0&0&0&-k_{m}\,\sin \left( \alpha
 \right) &k_{m}\,\cos \left( \alpha \right) &k_{m}+k_{{\it ru}}&0&0&0&
k_{m}\,\sin \left( \alpha \right) &-k_{m}\,\cos \left( \alpha \right) 
&-k_{m}\\ \noalign{\medskip}0&0&0&0&0&0&-k_{m}\, \left( \cos \left( 
\alpha \right)  \right) ^{2}+k_{m}+k_{s}&k_{m}\,\cos \left( \alpha
 \right) \sin \left( \alpha \right) &k_{m}\,\sin \left( \alpha
 \right) &k_{m}\, \left( \cos \left( \alpha \right)  \right) ^{2}-k_{m
}&-k_{m}\,\cos \left( \alpha \right) \sin \left( \alpha \right) &k_{m}
\,\sin \left( \alpha \right) \\ \noalign{\medskip}0&0&0&0&0&0&k_{m}\,
\cos \left( \alpha \right) \sin \left( \alpha \right) &k_{m}\, \left( 
\cos \left( \alpha \right)  \right) ^{2}+k_{s}&k_{m}\,\cos \left( 
\alpha \right) &-k_{m}\,\cos \left( \alpha \right) \sin \left( \alpha
 \right) &-k_{m}\, \left( \cos \left( \alpha \right)  \right) ^{2}&k_{
m}\,\cos \left( \alpha \right) \\ \noalign{\medskip}0&0&0&0&0&0&k_{m}
\,\sin \left( \alpha \right) &k_{m}\,\cos \left( \alpha \right) &k_{m}
+k_{{\it su}}&-k_{m}\,\sin \left( \alpha \right) &-k_{m}\,\cos \left( 
\alpha \right) &k_{m}\\ \noalign{\medskip}-k_{p}&0&0&k_{m}\, \left( 
\cos \left( \alpha \right)  \right) ^{2}-k_{m}&k_{m}\,\cos \left( 
\alpha \right) \sin \left( \alpha \right) &k_{m}\,\sin \left( \alpha
 \right) &k_{m}\, \left( \cos \left( \alpha \right)  \right) ^{2}-k_{m
}&-k_{m}\,\cos \left( \alpha \right) \sin \left( \alpha \right) &-k_{m
}\,\sin \left( \alpha \right) &-2\,k_{m}\, \left( \cos \left( \alpha
 \right)  \right) ^{2}+2\,k_{m}+k_{p}&0&-2\,k_{m}\,\sin \left( \alpha
 \right) \\ \noalign{\medskip}0&-k_{p}&-k_{p}&k_{m}\,\cos \left( 
\alpha \right) \sin \left( \alpha \right) &-k_{m}\, \left( \cos
 \left( \alpha \right)  \right) ^{2}&-k_{m}\,\cos \left( \alpha
 \right) &-k_{m}\,\cos \left( \alpha \right) \sin \left( \alpha
 \right) &-k_{m}\, \left( \cos \left( \alpha \right)  \right) ^{2}&-k_
{m}\,\cos \left( \alpha \right) &0&2\,k_{m}\, \left( \cos \left( 
\alpha \right)  \right) ^{2}+k_{p}&0\\ \noalign{\medskip}0&0&0&k_{m}\,
\sin \left( \alpha \right) &-k_{m}\,\cos \left( \alpha \right) &-k_{m}
&k_{m}\,\sin \left( \alpha \right) &k_{m}\,\cos \left( \alpha \right) 
&k_{m}&-2\,k_{m}\,\sin \left( \alpha \right) &0&2\,k_{m}\end {array}
 \right] 
}

\end{split}

\end{split}
\]



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would create some notations for sub-matrices and insert them instead of the raw elements.

Comment: Thanks! the problem is that I'm exporting this code from symbolic software, and I have lots of longer matrices than this one, I'm looking for an "automated" way of showing them in a page so I don't have to edit them one by one. Is there a way to do this? thanks.

Comment: @Roy - A very serious issue you will have to confront is that the software you're using to create the matrices generates seriously inefficient and inelegant code. For instance, there is simply no justification for *even one* of the 156 [!] instances of `\left(` and `\right)` -- `(` and `)` will do just fine. Actually, `(` and `)` will do a lot *better*, since there will an immediate space-saving effect.

Comment: What are your readers supposed to "get" from staring at 12x12 (and even larger...) matrices? If the honest answer is "nothing at all, in all likelihood", you should consider not showing the matrices at all. The readers of your document will appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks for your comments @Mico, I do realize the code is very bad, but there's actually nothing I can do about that. And you're right about showing the matrix, I just wanted to point out the problem I'm having and if anyone has an idea that might help me out.

Comment: The matrix seems to be a 4×4 block matrix with blocks of size 3×3. If all your auto generated matrices have this structure, you should be able to automate post processing and list the blocks separately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've attempted to modify your machine-generated code to make its output less of a space hog. E.g., I've replaced all 156 [!!] instances of `\left(` and `\right)` with `(` and `)`, for a very significant space saving. One should go farther, e.g. get rid of all instances of parentheses in `\cos(\alpha)` and `\sin(\alpha)` -- trust me, all those parentheses take up a *lot* of space. Likewise, I've gotten rid of all 50+ instances of `\,`. Even with all these optimizations, it's almost certainly necessary to switch to landscape mode and to employ a `\resizebox` directive.

The result is well-nigh unreadable, if you ask me. Your readers will get either very little or next to nothing out of glancing at the typeset matrix. If this were my document and I had to show several 12x12 matrices, I would either refuse to do so or I'd show four separate 6x6 matrices or four separate 12x3 matrices.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,rotating}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set page parameters suitably

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{12}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.25}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
$\begin{bmatrix}
k_p+k_c &0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0& -k_p &0&0\\ 
0&k_p+k_c&k_p&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&-k_p&0\\ 
0&k_p&k_p+k_{\mathit{cu}}&0&0&0&0&0&0&0
  &-k_p&0\\ 
0&0&0&-k_m (\cos\alpha)^2+k_m+k_r
  &-k_m\cos\alpha \sin\alpha &-k_m\sin\alpha 
  &0&0&0&k_m (\cos\alpha)^2-k_m
  &k_m\cos\alpha \sin\alpha &k_m\sin\alpha \\ 
0&0&0&-k_m\cos\alpha \sin\alpha 
  &k_m (\cos\alpha)^2+k_r& k_m\cos\alpha 
  &0&0&0& k_m\cos\alpha \sin\alpha 
  & -k_m(\cos\alpha)^2& -k_m\cos\alpha \\ 
0&0&0&-k_m\sin\alpha &k_m\cos\alpha 
  &k_m+k_{\mathit{ru}}&0&0&0&k_m\sin\alpha 
    &-k_m\cos\alpha &-k_m\\ 
0&0&0&0&0&0&-k_m (\cos\alpha)^2+k_m+k_s
  &k_m \cos\alpha \sin\alpha &k_m\sin\alpha 
  &k_m (\cos\alpha)^2-k_m&-k_m\cos\alpha \sin\alpha 
  &k_m \sin\alpha \\ 
0&0&0&0&0&0&k_m\cos\alpha \sin\alpha 
  &k_m (\cos\alpha)^2+k_s&k_m\cos\alpha 
  &-k_m\cos\alpha \sin\alpha 
  &-k_m (\cos\alpha)^2& k_m\cos\alpha \\ 
0&0&0&0&0&0&k_m\sin\alpha &k_m\cos\alpha 
  &k_m+k_{\mathit{su}}&-k_m\sin\alpha 
  &-k_m\cos\alpha &k_m\\ 
-k_p&0&0&k_m (\cos\alpha)^2-k_m
  &k_m\cos\alpha \sin\alpha & k_m\sin\alpha 
  &k_m (\cos\alpha)^2-k_m&-k_m\cos\alpha \sin\alpha 
  &-k_m\sin\alpha &-2k_m (\cos\alpha)^2 +2k_m+k_p
  &0&-2k_m\sin\alpha\\ 
0&-k_p&-k_p&k_m\cos\alpha \sin\alpha 
  &-k_m (\cos\alpha)^2 & -k_m\cos\alpha 
  &-k_m\cos\alpha \sin\alpha &-k_m (\cos\alpha)^2
  &-k_m\cos\alpha &0&2k_m (\cos\alpha)^2+k_p&0\\ 
0&0&0&k_m\sin\alpha &-k_m\cos\alpha &-k_m
  &k_m\sin\alpha &k_m\cos\alpha &k_m
  &-2k_m\sin\alpha &0&2k_m
\end{bmatrix}$}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well it's a symmetric matrix so half of it is redundant, not gonna help with the spacing though.

Comment: Thanks @Mico for taking the time of making my matrix pretty and the code. I agree with you on the readability, I think I'm gonna end up breaking the matrices into smaller ones and applying your code yo the smaller ones.

Comment: @percusse - Good point. If the OP decides to break up the 12x12 matrix into four 6x6 matrices, the one on the upper right (or lower left) may be omitted. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Resize it to the landscape view:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}
\usepackage{pdflscape}   
\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\noindent
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{$%
        \left[ \begin {array}{cccccccccccc} k_{p}+k_{c}&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&-k_{p
        }&0&0\\ \noalign{\medskip}0&k_{p}+k_{c}&k_{p}&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&-k_{p}&0
        \\ \noalign{\medskip}0&k_{p}&k_{p}+k_{{\it cu}}&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&-k_{p}&0
        \\ \noalign{\medskip}0&0&0&-k_{m}\, \left( \cos \left( \alpha \right) 
        \right) ^{2}+k_{m}+k_{r}&-k_{m}\,\cos \left( \alpha \right) \sin
        \left( \alpha \right) &-k_{m}\,\sin \left( \alpha \right) &0&0&0&k_{m
        }\, \left( \cos \left( \alpha \right)  \right) ^{2}-k_{m}&k_{m}\,\cos
        \left( \alpha \right) \sin \left( \alpha \right) &k_{m}\,\sin \left( 
        \alpha \right) \\ \noalign{\medskip}0&0&0&-k_{m}\,\cos \left( \alpha
        \right) \sin \left( \alpha \right) &k_{m}\, \left( \cos \left( \alpha
        \right)  \right) ^{2}+k_{r}&k_{m}\,\cos \left( \alpha \right) &0&0&0&
        k_{m}\,\cos \left( \alpha \right) \sin \left( \alpha \right) &-k_{m}\,
        \left( \cos \left( \alpha \right)  \right) ^{2}&-k_{m}\,\cos \left( 
        \alpha \right) \\ \noalign{\medskip}0&0&0&-k_{m}\,\sin \left( \alpha
        \right) &k_{m}\,\cos \left( \alpha \right) &k_{m}+k_{{\it ru}}&0&0&0&
        k_{m}\,\sin \left( \alpha \right) &-k_{m}\,\cos \left( \alpha \right) 
        &-k_{m}\\ \noalign{\medskip}0&0&0&0&0&0&-k_{m}\, \left( \cos \left( 
        \alpha \right)  \right) ^{2}+k_{m}+k_{s}&k_{m}\,\cos \left( \alpha
        \right) \sin \left( \alpha \right) &k_{m}\,\sin \left( \alpha
        \right) &k_{m}\, \left( \cos \left( \alpha \right)  \right) ^{2}-k_{m
        }&-k_{m}\,\cos \left( \alpha \right) \sin \left( \alpha \right) &k_{m}
        \,\sin \left( \alpha \right) \\ \noalign{\medskip}0&0&0&0&0&0&k_{m}\,
        \cos \left( \alpha \right) \sin \left( \alpha \right) &k_{m}\, \left( 
        \cos \left( \alpha \right)  \right) ^{2}+k_{s}&k_{m}\,\cos \left( 
        \alpha \right) &-k_{m}\,\cos \left( \alpha \right) \sin \left( \alpha
        \right) &-k_{m}\, \left( \cos \left( \alpha \right)  \right) ^{2}&k_{
            m}\,\cos \left( \alpha \right) \\ \noalign{\medskip}0&0&0&0&0&0&k_{m}
        \,\sin \left( \alpha \right) &k_{m}\,\cos \left( \alpha \right) &k_{m}
        +k_{{\it su}}&-k_{m}\,\sin \left( \alpha \right) &-k_{m}\,\cos \left( 
        \alpha \right) &k_{m}\\ \noalign{\medskip}-k_{p}&0&0&k_{m}\, \left( 
        \cos \left( \alpha \right)  \right) ^{2}-k_{m}&k_{m}\,\cos \left( 
        \alpha \right) \sin \left( \alpha \right) &k_{m}\,\sin \left( \alpha
        \right) &k_{m}\, \left( \cos \left( \alpha \right)  \right) ^{2}-k_{m
        }&-k_{m}\,\cos \left( \alpha \right) \sin \left( \alpha \right) &-k_{m
        }\,\sin \left( \alpha \right) &-2\,k_{m}\, \left( \cos \left( \alpha
        \right)  \right) ^{2}+2\,k_{m}+k_{p}&0&-2\,k_{m}\,\sin \left( \alpha
        \right) \\ \noalign{\medskip}0&-k_{p}&-k_{p}&k_{m}\,\cos \left( 
        \alpha \right) \sin \left( \alpha \right) &-k_{m}\, \left( \cos
        \left( \alpha \right)  \right) ^{2}&-k_{m}\,\cos \left( \alpha
        \right) &-k_{m}\,\cos \left( \alpha \right) \sin \left( \alpha
        \right) &-k_{m}\, \left( \cos \left( \alpha \right)  \right) ^{2}&-k_
        {m}\,\cos \left( \alpha \right) &0&2\,k_{m}\, \left( \cos \left( 
        \alpha \right)  \right) ^{2}+k_{p}&0\\ \noalign{\medskip}0&0&0&k_{m}\,
        \sin \left( \alpha \right) &-k_{m}\,\cos \left( \alpha \right) &-k_{m}
        &k_{m}\,\sin \left( \alpha \right) &k_{m}\,\cos \left( \alpha \right) 
        &k_{m}&-2\,k_{m}\,\sin \left( \alpha \right) &0&2\,k_{m}\end {array}
        \right]     
$}
\end{landscape} 

\end{document}
```

[image]